# FTP client in .NET Core

Tags: c#, ftp, .net-core, ftp-client

Can I download file / list files via FTP protocol using **netcoreapp1.0**?

I know, I can use [FtpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest) or [FluentFTP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentFTP) if I target full **.net45** framework.

My solution, however, is all based on .NET Standard 1.6 and I don't want to support full framework just to have FTP.

Comment: You have to wait till .NET Standard 2.0.

Answer (score 15):

### Edit for .net 6

`FtpWebRequest` is deprecated in .net 6.0.

As such, consider using [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP) (previously known as System.Net.FtpClient).

It is released under The MIT License and available on NuGet.

### For prior .net versions:

`FtpWebRequest` is now supported in .NET Core 2.0. See [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/2.0.0/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/FtpWebRequest.cs)

Example usage:

```
public static byte[] MakeRequest(
    string method, 
    string uri, 
    string username, 
    string password, 
    byte[] requestBody = null)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.Method = method;
    //Other request settings (e.g. UsePassive, EnableSsl, Timeout set here)
    
    if (requestBody != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream requestMemStream = new MemoryStream(requestBody))
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestMemStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
        }
    }

    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (MemoryStream responseBody = new MemoryStream())
    {
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(responseBody);
        return responseBody.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Where the value for the `method` parameter is set as a member of `System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp`.

See also [FTP Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/ftp)

Comment: `WebRequest` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated) in .Net 6. They write about it: `For FTP, since HttpClient doesn't support it, we recommend using a third-party library.` So, the way to go is now to use a third party library like FluentFTP.

Answer (score 13):

[FluentFTP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentFTP) now supports .NET core / .NET standard 1.6. If you run into problems please add an issue in the issue tracker and we'll work on it.

Edit 1:
Examples of using: https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/tree/master/FluentFTP.CSharpExamples

Comment: What a sad library. Does not follow any dotnet standards :(

Answer (score 12):

**FtpWebRequest** is now included to **.NET Standard 2.0**

FluentFTP library is also compatible with latest .net standard 2.0

Comment: if you need sftp support, FluentFTP doesn't support, but https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET does and supports .NET Standard 1.3.

Comment: Note: DE0003: WebRequest shouldn't be used - https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md

Comment: is FtpWebRequest use in .netcore application?

Comment: `WebRequest` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated) in .Net 6. They write about it: `For FTP, since HttpClient doesn't support it, we recommend using a third-party library.` So, the way to go is now to use a third party library like FluentFTP.

Answer (score 6):

There are no FTP capabilities out-of-the-box for netcoreapp1.0 or netstandard1.6. [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.method?view=netcore-2.1) will return in netstandard2.0.

Comment: Make sense. Can't wait for 2.0 so I had to create small .net46 app that downloads files from FTP and stores them in local folder. Main .netcore app uses FileSystemWatcher to monitor the folder and process these files when they appear.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using [FtpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-download-files-with-ftp) method.

Sample:

```
public static byte[] DownloadFile(string url, string filePath, string user, string password)
        {
            var ftpServerUrl = string.Concat(url, filePath);
            var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(ftpServerUrl);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user,password);
            using (var response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                responseStream?.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Keep in mind, that the the ftpServerUrl has to be a valid uri path containing the file path. e.g. `ftpServerUrl = "ftp://ftp.server/targetfile.txt"`