# .Net 6: Correct way to create a FtpWebRequest-object

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, ftp-client

In C# using .Net6 we can interact with an FTP-server using an [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=net-6.0)-object. This works well. But how should we create this object?
Currently we use [`WebRequest.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create?view=net-6.0)
and [Microsoft says we should do exactly this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=net-6.0#remarks).

But this function is obsolete now. So when the `Create`-function is obsolete but the `FtpWebRequest`-type is not, what is the correct and recommended way of creating a `FtpWebRequest`-object without using obsolete functions?

Comment: Arguably the method is obsolete only for the specific purpose of instantiating an `HttpWebRequest`. This also happens to be the most common use, so the `ObsoleteAttribute` makes sense. This attribute can't be made sophisticated enough to detect the non-obsolete use cases. I'd simply suppress the warning in this case. If you feel uncomfortable doing this every time, a simple helper method could be written (`CreateFtpWebRequest(Uri uri) => uri.Scheme != "ftp" ? throw new ArgumentException(...) : (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri)`, add `#pragma warning disable` to taste).

Comment: As Microsoft says you should use third-party library that ``FluentFtp`` is the best I think, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FTP client in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600312/ftp-client-in-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft clearly says to work with third-party and do not use any of their built-in libraries:

https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md

They says 'pick up a third-party library from the following list' and adding a  link that pointing to StackOverflow, to the following thread:
[Free FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371964/free-ftp-library)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Microsoft Learn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest), the FtpWebRequest class implements a File Transfer Protocol (FTP) client that you can use to interact with an FTP server. To create an instance of this class, you can use the WebRequest.Create a method and cast the result to FtpWebRequest. However, this method is marked as obsolete in .NET 6 and later versions, because it is mainly used for creating HttpWebRequest instances, which are no longer recommended.

The documentation suggests using a third-party library that supports FTP, such as [FluentFTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/ftp), instead of using the FtpWebRequest class. This library provides a more modern and efficient way of working with FTP servers, and it supports async/await, SSL/TLS, proxies, hashing, and many other features.

Alternatively, you can use the WebClient class to perform basic FTP operations, such as uploading and downloading files, without casting the result to FtpWebRequest. The WebClient class also supports async/await and cancellation tokens, and it is not marked as obsolete. You can find some examples of using the WebClient class for FTP in the Microsoft Learn documentation and the [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/667201/ftpwebrequest) article.